# Can I use a MIDI computer cable as a straight through male-to-male MIDI cable?

Tags: midi, cable

I have a UA-4FX USB interface that has one MIDI IN and one MIDI OUT DIN5 connectors.

My Casio keyboard has the same.

I have two MIDI "computer" cables like so:

[image: cable]

Is it possible to link this up (or just use one cable, but run the MIDI IN portion of the cable to the OUT of the keyboard, and the MIDI OUT portion of the cable to the IN of the UA-4FX)?  Any combination of one and/or two of these cables going to work or do I need to purchase a male-to-male DIN5 cable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the cable will work by itself.

If you connect it to a computer and tell your software to use MIDI out as MIDI thru, it should work, but you might experience some latency.

For convenience and reliability (and to reduce latency) I recommend getting a regular MIDI cable.  You can [find them on Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/gp/search/ref=sr_nr_p_36_5?bbn=11091801&keywords=midi%20cable&sort=relevancerank&qid=1325098263&rh=k%3amidi%20cable,n:11091801&rnid=386685011&low-price=&high-price=5&x=0&y=0) for under $5.

If you are adventurous, you could probably make your own by cutting and splicing the cables you already have.  This would require some knowledge of cable making and the proper cable pinout.

Comment: +1. I tried this on a similar cable that I own and can confirm it doesn't work.